# How to skip an element in nth-child?

Tags: html, css

I want to skip counting on an element in nth-child with :not attribute, but it does not work or it's not even possible to do. Is there any other way to do this?

Here is the code:

```css
.layout {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.layout:not(.hidden):nth-child(2n+1) {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout"></div>
<div class="layout"></div>
<div class="layout hidden"></div>
<div class="layout"></div>
<div class="layout"></div>
<div class="layout"></div>
<div class="layout"></div>
<div class="layout"></div>
```

Even though the element with class **.hidden** is not visible, it's still counted with **nth-child**

Comment: the answer is simple = you cannot like this ... the only way is to use nth-of-type and change the type of the hidden element

Comment: This element is generated on the fly by a 3rd party library and I need to hide it. The only thing that I have is this class. I guess there's no easy solution for this though

Comment: a CSS only solution i don't think so

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `:nth-child` can be applied to the result of evaluation of `:not`. But I suggest you a walkaround to get the same effect:

1. Wrap the "layout" DIVs within a `container` DIV:

```html
    <div id="container">
        <div class="layout"></div>
        <div class="layout"></div>
        <div class="layout hidden"></div>
        <div class="layout"></div>
    </div>
```

2. CSS:

```css
.layout {
/*float: left;*/
display: inline-table;
width: 100px;
height: 60px;
border: 2px solid red;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

div#container {
width: 232px; /* See the note below */
}

div.layout:first-child {
display: block;
clear: both;
}

.hidden {
display: none;
}

/*
.layout:not(.hidden):nth-child(2n+1) {
clear: both;
}
*/
```

To calculate accurately the container's exact width, you should first strip off the newlines between the `layout` DIVs, because they add an arbitrary amount of space when being rendered.

Comment: can you explain how this answer the question ? Sorry but i see no relation

Comment: @TemaniAfif Sure: Executing the OP's script, I've seen the author wants to render a set of boxes in two-columns layout (except the first of them, which is alone in its row), and that the hidden boxes must not be shown nor occupy any space. He/she has failed to accomplish this through the `nth-child` rule, so I have done it by an alternative means in this particular case.

Comment: sorry but it has nothing to do with what the OP want ... he's asking if we can ommit one element from the counting of nth-child ... if he *hidden* element is the 5th one, we want to make it the one after it the 5th one so that we count all the element without considering the hidden one and this is not possible with CSS

Comment: That's right: That is not possible in CSS3, I've started by saying that. So it is necessary to look for alternative solutions. Not always you can get what you want _in the way you want_, but you may get it by other means.

Answer (score -1):

HTML

```
<div class="content">
<div class="layout"></div>
<div class="layout"></div>
<div class="layout hidden"></div>
<div class="layout"></div>
<div class="layout"></div>
<div class="layout"></div>
<div class="layout"></div>
<div class="layout"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.content{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 224px
}
.layout {
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  flex: 1 0 30%;
}

.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```